# Python Dictionary and List Comparing

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to compare each item in a the list "lines" to the dictionary "dic", and then add the item from lines to dic if it doesn't exist, or add 1 to the value of the key in the dictionary.

```
import string

def uniques():
    file = open("test.txt", "r")
    dic = {}
    data = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    strip = removePunctuation(data)
    lines = strip.split(' ')
    print(strip)
    print(lines)

    for item in lines:

        #this produces an error of unhashable type: 'list'
        if lines in dic:
            dic[item] = dic[item] + 1
        else:
            print("else ran")
            dic[item] = 1

    for item in dic:
        print(item, dic[item])
        print("There are " + str(len(dic)) + " items in the dictionary")

def removePunctuation(text):
    text = text.strip()
    return text.rstrip(string.punctuation)

uniques()
```

Comment: Are you doing this for practice or do you just need the result? If the second have a look at `collections .Counter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its

```
if item in dic:
      dic[item] = dic[item] + 1
```

instead of

```
if lines in dic:
      dic[item] = dic[item] + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if item in dic.values():
```

instead of `if lines in dic:`

This would create a dict_value list.